# Kendo MVVM Grid, filtering multicheckbox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm, kendo-multiselect

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-multi-checkboxes

I'm using something like this with kendo MVVM:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
        <div class="box wide">
            <div data-role="grid"
                 data-filterable="{ mode: 'row' , cell: { showOperators: false, operator: 'contains' } }"
                 data-sortable="true"
                 data-columns="[
                    { 'field': 'TaskId', 'title': 'Actions', 'width': 100, filterable: false, template: viewModel.GenerateEditTemplate, sortable: false },
                    { 'field': 'IsCompleted', 'title': 'Completed', 'type' : 'boolean', 'width': 125, filterable: { messages: { isFalse: 'No', isTrue: 'Yes'  } } },
                    { 'field': 'Title', 'title': 'Title', 'width': 250, 'type' : 'string', filterable: { multi: true, dataSource: [{ Title: 'title1' }, { Title: 'title2' }] } },
                    { 'field': 'Hours', 'title': 'Estimated Hours', 'width': 110, 'type' : 'number', filterable: { cell: { showOperators: false, operator: 'contains' } } },
                    { 'field': 'CreatedBy', 'title': 'Created By', 'width': 150, filterable: { cell: { showOperators: false, operator: 'contains', template: viewModel.UserFilter  } } }
                 ]"
                 data-bind="source: TaskDataSource, events: { dataBound: OnDataBound }">
            </div>

        </div>
```

After that, the only filter displayed in the header is the input that allows me to filter the column but not the expected dropdown with the given data source.

Does anyone know if there is a limitation with KendoMVVM that doesn't allow me to use the multi-option into the filterable but it works on that KendoGrid configuration?

Thanks a lot